# Debug FastAPI application in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fastapi, uvicorn

i'm trying to debug an application (a web api) that use FastAPI (uvicorn)
I'm also using poetry and set the projev virtual environment in vscode.

i read [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/) tutorial to setup uvicorn and [this one](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) to setup vscode but i think i'm doing something wrong in set it up.

I tried to setup the launch.json both as **python: module** and **python: current file**

The problem seems that it doesn't recognize the project structure cause when i run the debug it stopped in an import statement with this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is my current launch.json configuration:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: local debug",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/topic_service/service/__init__.py",
        "args" : ["--port", "8000"]
    },
]
```

I also tried to add a .env file setting PYTHONPATH:

```
PYTHONPATH=.:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Locally i run the application as follow:

```
poetry run uvicorn src.main:app --port 8080 --reload
```

Does anyone know how to correctly **setup vscode to debug an uvicorn application**?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
I also tried what [this article](https://blog.hipolabs.com/remote-debugging-with-vscode-docker-and-pico-fde11f0e5f1c) says. the debugger seems to start but nothing happen (no breakpoint is triggered)

Answer (score 62):

Try this configuration.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "uvicorn",
    "args": ["src.main:app","--reload"]
}
```

Comment: this works, but now how can I launch the uvicorn + [opentelemetry-instrument](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/getting-started/#run-the-instrumented-app)?

Answer (score 35):

Likewise you provide `uvicorn` *module* with necessary *args* during development of FastAPI application, you need to configure your `launch.json` located in `.vscode` directory with respective values.

I did a write up for custom project configurations to [debug FastAPI in VS Code here](https://www.tutlinks.com/debug-fastapi-in-vs-code-ide/)

Suppose you issue the following command to run FastAPI on uvicorn server with args mentioned as below

```bash
uvicorn main:app --reload --port 8000
```

then your `launch.json` should have *module* with value of `uvicorn` and each of the *args* separated by space as items of the `args` array.

```json
"module": "uvicorn",
"type": "debugpy",
"request": "launch",
"args": [
    "main:app",
    "--reload",
    "--port",
    "8000"
],
"env": {
    "usersecret": "some$Ecret",
}
```

You can have this `launch.json` file in `.vscode` and then modify the `args` array in the JSON configuration as per your project structure.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: FastAPI",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "env": {
                "db_username": "postgres",
                "db_password": "secret",
                "host_server": "localhost",
                "database_name": "fastapi",
                "ssl_mode": "prefer",
                "db_server_port": "5432"
            },
            "args": [
                "main:app",
                "--reload",
                "--port",
                "8000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you can also specify from where to get the `.env` file instead of declaring each environment variable in the "env" property, just by adding the property -> `"envFile": "./some_folder/foo/.env"`

Comment: I was able to get the debugger working thanks to your tutorial, however I'm unable to get breakpoints anywhere but **main.py** to get detected. I tried setting `justMyCode = false` in **settings.json** to no effect. Why could that be?

Answer (score 20):

For me worked with this configurations:

On Debug section on VSCode, choose create launch.json option. Probally it will open launch.json on .vscode folder in your root folder explorer
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVzDJ.png), inside of launch.json put this:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: FastAPI",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "uvicorn",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/<folder to your main.py>",
      "args": [
        "main:app",
        "--reload",
        "--port", //these arg are optional
        "3003"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now , just run your debugger and have a nice day!

**Edit:** The cwd ensure that your debbuger will find the right path to your main.py file. So, for whos use multiple debuggers or uses outside vsCode with launch.json it's a nice choice use it.

Comment: Personally I use debugger on VSCODE in .vscode directory with launch.json. But there`s an way to use it inside vscode, maybe you going to have problems for yours debugger find where your main.py is it. So If you simply need run your fastAPI aplication the simplest way is use cwd with your debugger.

Comment: That explanation for adding the `cwd` should go into the answer. You can use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69901523/edit) button at the bottom of your answer to update it.

Answer (score 11):

The quick and easy way: launch debugger  <kbd>F5</kbd> and then select `FastAPI` Debug Configuration:
(p.s. this works on the VSCode Insiders; haven't tried it on a regular version)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The way i debug is quite basic, hope it helps
i have .py file with this config:

```py
import uvicorn
from app.main import api
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dev = 1
    if dev==0:
        #use this one
        uvicorn.run(api, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
    if dev == 1:
        #or this one
        uvicorn.run('app.main:api', host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info", reload=True, debug=True)
    if dev == 2:
        uvicorn.run('app.main:api', host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info", workers=2)
```

and run the file with the vscode debugger, **the important thing is to run the app with the** `debug` **flag because otherwise the debugger skips the breakpoints (at least in my case)**

Comment: with uvicorn version 0.20.0, there is no debug parameter...