# VSCode and FastAPI debugging - doesn't break within routes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, fastapi

Just getting started with FastAPI, but running into issues with trying to get it to recognize breakpoints in the VSCode debugger. The strange thing is that it does successfully break on lines that are not contained within routes

Pulling directly from the tutorial: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()  # breakpoint here works on launching file
print('here')    # breakpoint here works on launching file


@app.get("/")
def root():
    a = "a"   # breakpoint here does NOT work
    b = "b" + a
    return {"hello world": b}  # returns data successfully


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5002)
```

As commented above, the lines outside the routes work fine, and when I go to the address I get the data successfully, but the breakpoint within the route does not fire. Not sure what I'm missing here. Have tried various solutions from [Debug FastAPI application in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205056/debug-fastapi-application-in-vscode)

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but this is also running through the Remote-SSH extension on VSCode (my code is on a gcloud VM). Maybe this is contributing but again, the other breakpoints fire fine.

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: Looks like it does work if I replace "def" with "async def", though I'm trying to get this to work with a SQLite DB and per this page: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/ it recommends using "def" by default (with options to configure to use async def). I'll need to look into the distinction some more.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that although the method "`root()`" is defined in the code, we did not call this method in the code. When debugging, the debugger did not execute the code in the method.

Please try to add a statement that calls the method "`root()`" in the code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this isn't what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is when the user requests the URL, that the breakpoint fires. If I go to http://localhost:5002/ in my browser, it does execute the method because I get the response I expect back ({"hello world": 'ba'}), but it doesn't pause at the breakpoint. When I used Flask, it would do the behavior as expected on requests being triggered. I suppose I could create a file to call the function if I want to debug specific parameters, but seems like a roundabout way to do it.

Comment: @SSShah Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 see my edit at the bottom of the post. Never did get around to looking into it more (and don't use FastAPI anymore)

Comment: @SSShah Never mind, I figured out my problem. It was because I had a similar route defined just above the route I was trying to break point. So it just went there.