# How to configure VsCode to debug python uvicorn + open telemetry

Tags: python, open-telemetry, uvicorn, otel

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61000306/1830639) works for debugging FastAPI applications in VsCode.

But now I would like to debug FastAPI while using OpenTelemetry automatic instrumentation for python.

To run your python code with open telemetry, you need to run through the CLI like this ([example using Flask](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/getting-started/#run-the-instrumented-app)):

```
opentelemetry-instrument --traces_exporter console --metrics_exporter console --logs_exporter console --service_name dice-server flask run -p 8080
```

Now, how can I run like that using VsCode and still be able to debug FastAPI?

Here's my `launch.json`

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Uvicorn",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "uvicorn",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "args": [
            "server.main:app",
            //"--reload",
            "--port",
            "8000"
        ],
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- Use `"program": "${userHome}/.local/bin/opentelemetry-instrument"`assuming that  `opentelemetry-instrument` path is that one
- Use `"args": ["--traces_exporter","console",...,"uvicorn",...]`